# Is this a wrong approach to find whether array is subarray of another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, sub-array

```
bool isSubset(int arr1[], int m,int arr2[], int n){
    set<int> hashset;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        hashset.insert(arr1[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (hashset.find(arr2[i]) == hashset.end())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is this correct method to find whether `arr2` is sub array of `arr1` or not
because sub array is contiguous part of array but this code is not checking for any order that's why I want to be sure.

Comment: Try it and see. You seem to have a good idea of tests cases to try out.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by a "sub array" - that's not a term that has a universal definition.   Your function returns true if all elements of `arr2` are elements of `arr1`.     If you want to check if the sequence of all elements of `arr2` occur as a sequence in `arr1`, then your function does not meet your requirement.    For example,  `arr1 = {1,2,3,4}` and `arr2={3,2}` will test true according to your function, but the sequence `{3,2}` is not in `arr1`.

Comment: A subarray is a contiguous part of array, Like substring

Comment: `std::search` is a thing. Also, `std::set` is a treeset, not a hashset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct method to find whether arr2 is sub array of arr1 or not

No, it isn't. Your method doesn't consider the order of elements. It is more of a method to find whether a bunch of numbers (given in `arr2`) exist in an `arr1`.

For instance, if `int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3}` and `int arr2[] = {2, 1}`, the method you implemented will return `true`, while it should return `false`.

Here is how you would do it:

```c++
#include <iostream>

bool isSubset(int array[], int m, int subarray[], int n)
{
    if (n > m)
        return false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= m-n; i++) {
        int ii = i, j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (subarray[j] != array[ii])
                break;
            else
                ii++;
        
        if (j == n)
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```c++
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
    const int m = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    
    int subarray1[] = {1, 2};
    const int n1 = sizeof(subarray1) / sizeof(*subarray1);

    int subarray2[] = {2, 1};
    const int n2 = sizeof(subarray2) / sizeof(*subarray2);
    
    std::cout << isSubset(array, m, subarray1, n1) << "\n"; // Will print 1
    std::cout << isSubset(array, m, subarray2, n1) << "\n"; // Will print 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You understood that the way your code is checking subarray is wrong.

A suggestion-

Use of `C` language style array in `C++` is discouraged. Instead, you should use the appropriate standard container, provided in [Containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). You can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container in place of plain `C` style array. Below is the sample code to check subarray:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::array<int,12> arr1 {9,5,2,5,9,2,4,7,0,4,5,1};
    std::array<int,3> arr2 {5,9,2};
    bool res = false;    
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::array<int,12>::iterator x;

    while ((x = std::find(arr1.begin() + pos, arr1.end(), arr2[0])) != arr1.end()) {
        size_t currpos = x - arr1.begin();

        if ((arr1.size() - currpos >= arr2.size()) &&
           ((std::equal(arr1.begin() + currpos, arr1.begin() + currpos + arr2.size(), arr2.begin())))) {
            res = true;
            break;
        }

        pos = currpos + 1;
    }

    if (res) {
        std::cout << "arr2 is subarray of arr1" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "arr2 is not subarray of arr1" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```